# Bevel in Solidified Plane

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I created a plane and started working on it's corner to add some radius.

Now I want to smooth the edges (perimeter) of the plane. I tried to use Bevel but I am unable to do this as soon as I solidify the plane. Any clues why it doesn't work properly or how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange! Could you please add an image of what you are looking to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the Bevel *operator* to bevel the edges of your *Solidified* plane, without applying the modifier, because the edges don't exist at the time the operator is invoked. You can use a Bevel *modifier* to do it, below *Solidify* on the stack.

The first bevel, rounding the corners in XY, could be done with an operator, and that may be better, allowing you to, say, inset the plane, to avoid the normals in the triangulation of the large n-gon interpolating badly over the edges into the thickness. However here we go with modifiers all the way, on a once-subdivided plane..

- A bevel of the corner vertices only, by vertex-bevel-weight:

[image]

- Solidify, with defaults..

[image]

- Bevel the rim, by angle, again, with default settings out of view..

[image]

- The resulting normals aren't perfect, but can be fixed with a *Weighted Normal* modifier.

[image]

Comment: Although I solved this after taking too much time, I appreciate the reply! Hopefully it will help other folks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shape, you can get smooth corners without a Bevel, just use a *Subdivision Surface* instead. Put it above the *Solidify* modifier if you only want the corners rounded like in your picture, or put it below if you want it to round horizontally and vertically at the same time. See Below:

[image: SubdTop]

[image: SubdBottom]

Comment: Thank you I will try to get it work today!